# Sampling error with weighted mean

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, sampling

I am studying statistics and I am wondering when it comes to standard error or a sampling if the calculation changes when there are weights added.

I have a weighted mean:

$$\mu_{w} = \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_ix_i}{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i}$$
and a weighted variance calculated by:

$$s^2_{w}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i}{(\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^Nw_i^2}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^N(x_i-\mu)^2$$

is the sampling error still calculated as

$$\text{SE}=\sqrt{\dfrac{s^2_{w}}{n}}$$

Comment: According to the properties of the variance, Var(wX)=w^2 Var(x).

Comment: Only when $w$ is a constant.

Comment: This is somewhat related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25895/computing-standard-error-in-weighted-mean-estimation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike weighted mean and weighted variance which have definitions (although possibly multiple in the case of weighted variance), there does not seem to be a standardized definition for the weighted standard error of the mean ([Gatz & Smith, 1995](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/donald-gatz/weighted-standard-error.pdf)). Gatz and Smith give three examples in the paper. Some other sources would include this [paper from Stata](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/svyvarianceestimation.pdf), perhaps.

Comment: I will read these! Thank you!